# Is it possible to have a user agree to an amount, then take a deposit up front?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create a process where a user would agree to a full amount ($100), but only have to pay a 20% deposit up-front ($20) at the time. Then at a later time, trigger the remainder of the full amount ($80) to be billed.

Would this be possible to do with PayPal? I would like to avoid the user having to come back into PayPal to fulfill the final payment.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well,PayPal has this one useful product which they named it as Billing Agreement - Reference Transaction where you can set up an agreement with the buyer using Express Checkout. In this case, you set up an agreement with purchase of $20% (assumed $20)of the full amount, and then after a later time, you billed the customer using the agreement you established to charge the remainder 80% (assumed $80).

This is the link where you can get more understanding what I just suggested above.

Reference Transaction - Billing Agreement : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/